# Detect div when inside screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an menu like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ud100m3t/1/

I have a problem with this, how you can see, when you press right arrow some times, the menu is scrolling an blank space is filled since you finish your movements (setted in maxState variable, the total menu elements).

I want make this behaivour different: When last element appears on screen and you press again in right button, menu resets (like now when you press 7 times, menu scroll to opposite direction and starts in other side).

Current output: http://screencast.com/t/MS9H0ByPr
Desired output: http://screencast.com/t/1rHbgr6ZEuJ

This my example menu:

```
<nav id="sub" class="clearfix">
<div id="lefty">&lt;</div>
<div class="container_element">
    <div class="inner_container">
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Estimate</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">About</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Customer Information</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Financing</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Careers</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Locate Us</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="box">Inspiration</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="righty">&gt;</div>
</nav>
```

And this my javascript code:

```
 $(function(){
    var state = 0;
    var maxState = 7;
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        winWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.container_element').width(winWidth-100);
        $('.container_element').scrollLeft((winWidth-100)*state);
    }).trigger('resize');
    $('#lefty').click(function(){
        if (state==0) {
           state = maxState;
        } else {
           state--;
        }
        $('.container_element').animate({scrollLeft:($(".box").width()*state)+'px'}, 800);
    });
    $('#righty').click(function(){
        if (state==maxState) {
           state = 0;
        } else {
           state++;
        }
        $('.container_element').animate({scrollLeft:($(".box").width()*state)+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
```

(You can see the css in the fiddle)

I tried some weird combos with the width of the screen and the box widths but I only break more the menu. Any idea or help to continue with this? Thanks

Comment: Seems like poor usability to me. As a user I don't like the idea of clicking/scrolling through an unknown number of links that I cannot see to possibly find out that what I wanted wasn't there to begin with. Show me all the options at each level of hierarchy and let me drill down based on the options at each level.

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar, Anyway is a task that I have to complete :) It's hard but I think it's an interesting menu style

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this fixes your issue, but just for safety I would check the `state` variable with `<=` and `>=`:

```
$('#lefty').click(function(){
    if (state <= 0) {
    // [...]
});
$('#righty').click(function(){
    if (state >= maxState) {
    // [...]
});
```

You can also replace these if statements by shorter code like this:

```
$('#lefty').click(function() {
    state = (state <= 0) ? maxState : state - 1;
    // [...]
});

$('#righty').click(function() {
    state = (state >= maxState) ? 0 : state + 1;
    // [...]
});
```

While I was trying out your menu, I also noticed that if there are for example six of seven menu items visible, there are only two different states (instead of seven). If you know the width of the menu and the width of each menu item, you could calculate the number of states that are actually different.